# Остановить each при нажатии

Tags: jquery, функции, foreach, setinterval

Добрый день, есть задача остановить анимацию `div` при клике на него. Получается остановить всю функцию, но реализовать остановку для конкретного `div`, на который нажали, не получается.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#create").click(function(){
    var qanak=0;
    var interval=setInterval(function(){
    $("body").each(function(){
      var div=$("<div></div>");
      var posL=parseInt(Math.random()*600);
      var posT=parseInt(Math.random()*600);
      div.addClass("a "+"a"+qanak)
      div.css({left:posL+"px",top:posT+"px"})
      if(qanak<10){
        $("body").append(div);
      }
      qanak+=1;
      $("div").each(function(){
        var clas=parseInt(Math.random()*9);
        var posL=parseInt(Math.random()*600);
        var posT=parseInt(Math.random()*600);
        $(".a"+clas).animate({left:posL+"px", top:posT+"px", transition:0.5+"s"})
 })
      })
    },1000)
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    div{
      position: absolute;
      border:1px solid;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="create">Create</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: сколько элементов `body` Вы ожидаете посетить в цикле `$("body").each`?

Comment: $(".a"+clas).stop(); попробуйте

Answer (score 1):

Можно добавлять класс элементу при клике, и в функции которая анимирует проверять - если нету класса - анимируем.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#create").click(function() {
    var qanak = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      $("body").each(function() {
        var div = $("<div></div>");
        var posL = parseInt(Math.random() * 600);
        var posT = parseInt(Math.random() * 600);
        div.addClass("a " + "a" + qanak)
        div.css({
          left: posL + "px",
          top: posT + "px"
        })
        if (qanak < 10) {
          $("body").append(div);
        }
        qanak += 1;
        $("div").each(function() {
          var clas = parseInt(Math.random() * 9);
          var posL = parseInt(Math.random() * 600);
          var posT = parseInt(Math.random() * 600);
          let element = $(".a" + clas);
          if (!element.hasClass('fixed')) {
            $(".a" + clas).animate({
              left: posL + "px",
              top: posT + "px",
              transition: 0.5 + "s"
            })
          }

        })
      })
    }, 1000)
  })
})

$(document).on('click', '.a', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('fixed');
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    div {
      position: absolute;
      border: 1px solid;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <button id="create">Create</button>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Спасибо получилось